# How to embed Google Maps into an activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-view

I am currently trying to embed a Google Map into a custom View.

The only thing that the tutorial shows is how to make a full map xml and not a 'windowed' version.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your xml:

```
<!-- Map -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"">
</FrameLayout>
```

And in your code:

```
// This method adds map fragment to the container.
private void addMapFragment() {
    SupportMapFragment mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.map_container, mMapFragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Also use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you are inside a fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your custom view `xml` file, try changing the size of the map fragment. In the example below I set height and width to `30dp`.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context=".MapsActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
```

past in your activity xml file and change the id of fragment
ex:android:id="@+id/map1"

then

goto your java file and past after setcontent in on create

```
MapFragment  mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map1, mMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

implements onMapReadyCallBack method and overide in the activity

**Note:-this work only if you added Google map in application**